# What's the easiest way to distribute ribbon customizations to a mass amount of users?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, ribbon

I want to remove a specific button from displaying in the Outlook 2010 toolbar/ribbon.  I've already made the change on an individual machine and it seems to work fine.  How can I distribute a change of this nature to a mass amount of users?   Outlook lets me export all UI customizations as a `.exportedUI` file but I'm not sure what tool can be used to distribute it.  Is this purely for manual import use?

Comment: What does the Office Group Policy ADM templates let you do with such customisations? You could try pushing a registry setting out via Group Policy if the templates don't work out...

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I work in IT but I understand (now) that this doesn't fit under SuperUser.  I vote to close/move to ServerFault.